Can probability amplitudes be used as credences?
Probability amplitudes in quantum mechanics are sometimes called a "generalization" of probabilities. They are complex numbers a + bi. The probability associated with the probability amplitude is |a + bi|^2 = a^2 + b^2.
If probability amplitudes are really a generalization of probabilities, is it possible to use them as credences for everyday statements outside of quantum physics? So that a person might say they assign an 0.5 - 0.3i probability amplitude that it will rain. Is there a way to make such a statement sensible, in the same way that it is sensible to say there is an 80% chance it will rain?

Cox, A use of complex probabilities in the theory of stochastic processes. Weizsäcker considered "logic of complementarity" with complex truth values, see Khatam-Shafiee. One can use them to make people stop asking whether Schrödinger's cat is alive or dead before the box is open. But "everyday statements" rarely involve macroscopic superpositions.

@Conifold: I just did a search for 'complex' in Khatam-Shafiee. There were no matches. Can you please point out where they use "complex truth values"  in this paper?

@Conifold Thanks, your first link is more what I'm looking for. A process is first modeled with probabilities, then mapped to the complex domain via the Laplace transform, then it's explored what happens if the probabilities can take on complex values in this modeling while still giving real results when mapped back. This lets us say things like, "this process works as if it had transition probabilities 0.5 + 0.5i and 0.5 - 0.5i." Interesting, though seemingly narrow. I'd like to see it extended to an epistemic framework, if that were possible.

Sorry, wrong link on Weizsäcker. Should have been Parrochia, On von Weizsäcker's philosophy of Quantum Mechanics.

I don't know that there would be much use representing credences like this. In quantum mechanics, complex numbers are useful because they form an important part of the picture for why pieces of the wave function interfere with each other in the ways they do. If normal credences don't have interference patterns which are succinctly modelled by complex numbers, then it's probably not a particularly useful way to think about credences.

Probability amplitudes in quantum mechanics arise for a particular reason. Our best understanding of the physics of particles involves a wave equation, and this equation delivers complex solutions. The time-dependent Schrödinger equation even has an explicit i in it. These solutions allow us to describe the strange behaviours of quantum experiments such as the double slit experiment. Interpreting the square of the modulus of the amplitude as a probability density function (the Born rule) fits with empirical observation. In particular it yields results that agree with the concept of quantum superposition.
If we try to enquire what is the physical significance of a complex amplitude, it is difficult to understand or explain. It is just part of the weird way the universe behaves within quantum theory. If you favour the "shut up and calculate" approach to interpreting QM then you don't care what complex amplitudes or negative energies or negative probabilities mean, as long as they deliver useful results.
If you prefer an information theoretic interpretation of QM, you might well be content with the observation that using squared magnitudes is the only way to get a measure in state space that conserves probabilities. Since this is a highly desirable property in information theory, that justifies the use of it.
If you hold with the many worlds interpretation, which is more 'realistic', it makes more sense to enquire how the Born rule is justified. Some have claimed that the Born rule can be derived through counting of finite worlds. My understanding is that this claim is controversial, and justifying the Born rule is still a work in progress among theoreticians who favour the MWI.
My point is that without some empirical data that needs to be accounted for, or some feature of credences that we would like to explain, it is not clear why a second imaginary axis would be needed. Probabilities, under the Bayesian interpretation, work fine as a first approximation to rational degrees of credence. This has been justified by the work of Richard Cox and Bruno de Finetti.
The only analog with QM that I can imagine would be some theory that uses probabilities to describe the credences of an agent who entertains inconsistent beliefs but is still able to function properly and make sensible decisions. After all, we all do that. Maybe you could formulate a theory in which credences have complex values and when conflicting beliefs are combined for the purposes of making a decision they yield non-trivial probabilities by a process of belief superposition. Looks like a research project for someone. I'm surprised Kristian Berry hasn't already done it.

In quantum physics in general square amplitudes do not obey the rules of probability because of quantum interference. See Section 2 of this paper for an example:
https://arxiv.org/abs/math/9911150
If you interact with a quantum system and produce a record of its state that can be copied this will suppress interference, an effect called decoherence. See this review article especially Section 2:
https://arxiv.org/abs/1911.06282
The title of your question mentions credences: probabilities that are supposedly attached to theories, but the body of your question doesn't. The body of your question only mentions the probability of a future event: whether it will rain in your location.
There are papers about using quantum probabilities as credences in the light of David Deutsch's explanation of quantum probability in terms of decision theory. See these papers for some examples:
https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0211104
https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0312136
Other people have criticised using these probabilities as credences:
https://arxiv.org/abs/0905.0624
There are criticisms of the framing of this controversy. It is notable that Deutsch's original decision theory paper doesn't mention credences:
https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/9906015
The entire paper is about the behaviour of decision theoretic agents in preference ranking quantum states.
There are severe problems with the idea of credences. Defining probabilities requires a space of events and that space of events comes from some explanatory theory, such as quantum theory or whatever. As such the idea of the probability of a theory is gibberish since you have no space of events on which to define it. Another problem is that a theory is either right or wrong so what does the probability mean? There aren't multiple copies of the whole of physical reality on which you can define that probability. Yet another problem is that since a theory is right or wrong it's difficult to see how assigning a probability to it could be possibly be relevant to any real decision. You have to either accept or reject a theory if you're considering using it for some application including understanding some issue. If you want to understand radioactive decay it does you no good to say that quantum chromodynamics is 50% true since you can't half use it to calculate the cross section of a nuclear reaction. For more explanation see
https://criticalfallibilism.com/yes-or-no-philosophy/
https://criticalfallibilism.com/yes-or-no-philosophy-and-score-systems/
The probability of an event like "it will rain in my location at 2pm" can make sense. I wouldn't want to do the quantum calculation required to get that probability but there is no difficulty with doing it if you have vastly more computational resources than anyone has now, but the idea of doing isn't nonsense, unlike credences. The real role of probabilities in the assessment of theories is that if the observed relative frequencies of an event don't match the probabilities when some theory claims they should that creates a problem which has to be solved by either modifying the theory or coming up with a flaw in the experiment, as David Deutsch has pointed out:
https://arxiv.org/abs/1508.02048


As you say a probability amplitude in quantum mechanics (QM) is a
complex number. Only after taking the square of its modulus one
obtains a probability, which is a real number between zero and one.
The phase of the complex number is the reason that the probability
amplitudes of different states can interfere. This produces the
characteristic interference properties from the superposition of
quantum states in QM.
On the level of classical physics one does not observe any
interference of states: The interaction with the environment
produces the decoherence of the states. As a consequence any ability
of interference fades away during the transition from the QM-level
to the classical level.

Hence I do no see an explanatory value when replacing the real numbers of probabilities by the complex numbers of probability amplitudes.

tl;dr: Yes, but why?

If probability amplitudes are really a generalization of probabilities,

What do you mean by "really"? "Probability amplitude" is a man-made technical term for the value of the Schrödinger wavefunction. Being a wave, it has two properties: the amplitude and the phase. This is why you need two real numbers to fully describe it. It was Max Born's observation that it's "power" (i.e. the squared amplitude) corresponds to probability of an event.

is it possible to use them as credences for everyday statements outside of quantum physics? So that a person might say they assign an 0.5 - 0.3i probability amplitude that it will rain

To what end? As far as I know (and may physicists correct me if I'm wrong) probability amplitudes aren't observable in quantum mechanics. Even the probabilities are not observable, but have to be estimated from observing a large number of discrete events.
If you really wish, you can map not only complex numbers, but almost everything - words, sounds, images... - to numbers between 0 and 1 and hence consider them "generalized probabilities". This is, essentially, how many classification algorithms / predictive probabilistic models in machine learning and statistics work. This is in no way special to quantum mechanics and "probability amplitudes".

No, I don't think so. Ordinary probability has a frequentist interpretation and hence can be modelled by frequency of events. Whereas probability amplitudes has no such direct interpretation in the real world.
The generalisation of probability theory to the quantum realm is merely a formal generalisation and not of its interpretation. The closest approach is perhaps QBism which takes an epistemological approach to quantum probabilities. But these to interpret real world events but quantum phenomena.

But it is possible to represent credences with more than one number. For example, instead of just a probability, we could give a probability and an error bound. Or we could give a probability and how many data points the probability is based on. It's not inconceivable that a useful theory could involve numbers of the form a+bi, that map to probabilities via a^2 + b^2.

@causative: No, an error bound has nothing to do with probability but a measute of how much a partocular data point can vary by. Further the map you suggest doesn't actually use the complex numbers as complex numbers but merely a way of packaging two numbers tovether as a single number.

An error bound is not a probability but can conceivably be a credence. A credence could be any mental object that represents the attitude of a mind towards a proposition. Perhaps it would be more technically accurate to say "propositional attitude" instead of "credence." In any case, the attitude of a mind towards a proposition could have a lot of dimensions. A person might think a proposition is right in some parts and wrong in others, and the expression of which parts it is right in, and which parts it is wrong in (and even why), could all be components of the propositional attitude.

@causative: No, an error bound is not a credence. Nor is it concievably such either. Nor is a credence a mental object. Can you show me a mental object that I can pick up? A credence represents a measure of belief an observer has towards a particular proposition.

Why should this measure of belief be a single number? When you measure a house or a chair you don't just get one number. Length, height, breadth, and many more. There are a lot of different components to the measure.

I never said that this measure had to be a single number. You're simply speculating on what credence could be without giving a "technical" definition of such.

Well, that was the only reason I brought up error bounds: towards the point that the credence could be multiple numbers. Think of it this way, suppose you are designing a robot to do various tasks, and the robot has a belief set, and to each belief in the set is associated some data structure that tells the robot in what manner to process that belief. The data structure could be just one number, a probability. It could be two numbers, a probability and a confidence in that probability. It could be a hundred numbers; whatever ends up being useful to the robot. The data structure is a credence.

@causative: You're still not makimg the case that credence can be viewed as complex number. You're literally making stuff up. Do you have a reference for a credible thinker - someone who we can have  credence in - who has suggested this in a grounded way and not merely as speculation.

I'm making the case that there's no a priori reason to reject complex credences just because they aren't probabilities. I don't know if a coherent framework with complex credences has been made; that's why I asked the question.

@causative: And there is no a priori reason to think that the moon is not made of green cheese. The point I'm making is that you're advancing speculative claims with no backimg. No credible author has advanced a claim that credence can be thought of in terms of complex numbers. What does it mean to multiply two credences or to exponentiate them? There is no sense in them. Credence has been generally thought through - formally - in terms of modal logics. This does not include complex numbers in their definition last time I looked.

In his comment, Conifold gave links to two authors using complex numbers as credences. I'm looking into them.

@Causative: I just did a search for 'complex' in the Khatam-Shafiee that Conifold brought up. There were no matches.

OK, well, look at the other one then.

@causative: YOU look at the other one. It's your claim after all.

@causative: I've caught Conifold in mistakes before, so I'm not apt to put credence in his statements. Try putting that in a complex number.

I am looking at the other one. You know about sci-hub.se ?

@causative: No, I do not.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sci-Hub

@causative: I've asked Conifold where did he see the use of 'complex truth values' in Khatam-Shafiee because searching for it doesn't show anything. He hasn't answered yet. Let's see if he answers.

TL;DR: See last sentence.
Often, physics happens on a sphere. If you extend something past 100 percent, it rotates around and goes back to zero again, and while doing that, the values above 100% are imaginary. Angles work like this.
Spacetime does too, in 4 dimensions. If your velocity exceeds c, you'll find that your velocity is less than c but time is running backwards. Your velocity is complex. This is because physics treats elapsed time as negative distance.  4D distance (in spacetime, not generally) is called  "pseudometric."
Note that you convert elapsed time into a spatial distance by multiplying it by c. Hours x miles/hour = miles.
If you go 6 light years in 6 years, your 4-dimensional distance is 0. Yes, really. That's why entanglement happens. Things at 0 distance interact, even though both objects are distinct and separated in both space and time.
If you go 6 light years in 3 years, you've exceeded c, and your 4-dimensional distance is negative. You can represent the total distance as -3 light-years, which doesn't make sense in 3 dimensions (but does in 4), or as (6 + 3i) in strange units.
That is unnecessary in real domains. Sure, you could give the probability of flipping a coin heads as .5 + 0i, but the  imaginary part would always be zero.
